# How can I associate story_author name with request.user?

Tags: python, django, forms, associated-object

My first problem is once I save a story, the story.author will not associate with request.user.

So it brings to another problem, I have to add story_author from user list, and then select an author for the story manually.

[Here is my damin looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tcpon.png)

## models.py

```
class StoryAuthor(models.Model):
"""
Model representing a author.
"""
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

def get_absolute_url(self):
    """
    Returns the url to access a particular story_author instance.
    """

    return reverse('stories_by_author', args=[str(self.id)])

def __str__(self):
    """
    String for representing the Model object.
    """
    return self.user.username

class Story(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(StoryAuthor,related_name='stories',null=True)

    sb_thing = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    sb_story = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
    sb_name = models.CharField(max_length=30,null=True)
```

## views.py

```
def story_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
       form = StoryForm(request.POST)
       #form.StoryAuthor = request.user
       if form.is_valid():
           story = form.save(commit=False)
           StoryAuthor = request.user
           story.published_date = timezone.now()
           story.save()
           return redirect('story_detail', pk=story.pk)
       else:
           form = StoryForm()
           return render(request, 'story/story_create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: What's the point of the `StoryAuthor` model actually ? Why don't you just make `Story.author` a foreign key to `User` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your `StoryAuthor` model forces you to create the appropriate instance if necessary along the following lines:

```
if form.is_valid():
    story = form.save(commit=False)
    story.author, _ = StoryAuthor.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
    # ...
    story.save()
```

See the docs on [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).